# Is switching SQL Server installed edition from "Enterprise" to "Developer" allowed?

Tags: sql-server, upgrade

I attempted to change a SQL Server 2019 Enterprise edition to developer edition and it says it not allowed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNHyW.png)

Comment: So you see it's not allowed, then ask here whether or not it's allowed? What are you expecting?

Comment: Well - the Developer edition is functionally identical to Enterprise - ***BUT*** it does not come with a production license, e.g. you are not allowed to run production code on it - it's strictly for development / testing. Maybe that's the reason MS isn't allowing "upgrading" an Enterprise edition to Developer ....

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow dbagnew. remember to check out [tour] and learn [ask]. regarding the upgrade problem, you can do a fresh install of developer edition and import the old database there - not a straight upgrade. however, keep in mind using developer edition in production may result in legal trouble (see eula).

Comment: Is any installation of a SQL Server enterprise edition able to downgrade to developer edition or might they be components (SSRS, SSIS, SSAS, etc.) or features that prevent it? Thanks

Comment: I meant "what are you expecting" quite literally and no disrespect was intended. If the setup says "no", and your question is "is it allowed", then there's no real other answer than "no". Presumably that isn't what you're looking for, so then the question is what you *are* looking for, as in, what problem you're trying to solve and what feedback you're expecting.

Comment: marc_s , Yes, I'm aware of that issue. Thanks. Sadly, all are installation are in EE. We wanted to know if the switch from EE to DE was possible without a clean installed (or uninstall\install). Not sure of the limitation is across the board or due to something else. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking if there's a way to do the edition change despite the message?  In this case, it's not supported.  I likely would build a new server and do a migration if this had to be done.

The "one-way" migration path is not uncommon in version and edition upgrades.  Here is a link to the supported upgrade matrix.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades-2019?view=sql-server-ver16

Can a developer edition be in production or an enterprise edition in development by accident?  Sure.  If you have paid for a Enterprise license for a DEV edition production server, then you are likely good.  If you have MSDN, then you are okay for non-production use of non-DEV editions.

I never base our licensing on just the edition.  I seem to remember reading in a licensing whitepaper from Microsoft that the edition was not important, but the use was.  For example, a test setup using STD and ENT editions via MSDN was fine.  If any of it was production, then MSDN is not fine.

All the gory details:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Licensing/product-licensing/sql-server

https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/2/9/e29a9331-965d-4faa-bd2e-7c1db7cd8348/SQL_Server_2019_Licensing_guide.pdf

https://www.visualstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Visual-Studio-2017-Licensing-Whitepaper-March-2017.pdf

In the the last link "What Software is Included and Downgrade Rights" clearly indicates you can use any STD and ENT versions for non-production using MSDN.  This is why you can't use edition alone to determine licensing.  However, all those accessing the MSDN licensed servers must have MSDN with the exception of UAT.  A client testing the app would not need a MSDN license.  If anybody does not have MSDN, then a production license is required.  This is a where a DEV edition can be costly with an ENT license when a STD edition would have been used otherwise.

Comment: Randy, I will go through all the links and post. I know how those MS docs can be. I am SO not looking forward to doing a uninstall\install or install on 76 servers. I greatly appreciate the time you took to put this together. Thanks

Comment: 76 servers...you won't be bored.  Production on a DEV edition still requires a production ENT license even if the edition is DEV.  Development on Enterprise might look bad, but does it really require a production ENT license if it's development?  Might be worth asking your MS rep.  Who know, perhaps they have solution.

Comment: Randy, as if things can’t get any stranger... We went thru a mad dash of upgrading in place win 2012/sql 2012 servers a while ago. So I thought that may have had something to do with it. I requested a new win 2019 image and did some testing. A clean SQL 2017 EE install can be downgraded to DE. A clean SQL 2017 EE install and upgraded to 2019 EE can't be downgraded. A clean install of SQL 2019 EE can't be downgraded. As a side note a SQL 2019 DE edition can't be accesses from outside the server (I had to use SQLCMD). The same install using EE can. I'm beginning to question the media. Thanks.

Comment: @DBAgnew The protocol defaults vary by edition by design.  Was the design to secure or to confuse?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/default-sql-server-network-protocol-configuration?view=sql-server-ver16  I avoid upgrades in place...history is not always a good thing and I don't like the risk.

Comment: PS TCP being disabled by default for express and developer sort of makes sense.  A developer will likely be using the same PC for both development and hosting the database.  In this case shared memory is probably good enough.

Comment: I understand and agree with upgrades-in-place but had no choice. The current need is to save on licensing costs and there's a push to downgrade all EE non-prd SQL Server instances to DE. Thanks for the TCP on developer.

Comment: I wanted to give you a follow up. MS says you can't do a downgrade. BTW, do you know if I can restore a master database backup from a EE to the newly installed DE? If I need to open a different request no worries. Just let me know. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @DBAgnew The documentation indicates the versions of the backup source and target must be identical.  The details only mention the patch level, but I would not have much hope.  Have you tried it yet?  This is something that might be of interest. 
 https://docs.dbatools.io/Start-DbaMigration

Comment: I do use dbatools.io extensively but not that command. I will research. I did some experiment doing a restore to DE from a backup of the master db from EE version and as long as both are at the same patch level it works. I have an odd feeling on this approach as I get the sense sometime in the future it will go bump and MS will say this is not approved. MS says the code set between EE and DE are identical so I guess the edition setting is in the registry. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I compared media bits of editions (STD, DEV, ENT) a few years back. The only difference was the default PID which can be set during setup via config file or command line.  It sounds like it worked, but will there be a glitch someday from a ENT value in master and a DEV value in the registry?  I made a request to Microsoft to update their documentation to be clear about limitations in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-and-restore-of-system-databases-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: FYI https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/7771 It sounds like a restore of master from ENT to DEV should be fine.

Comment: I was aware of the sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features dmv, howerver I'm not clear on if this dmv focuses only on the "Scale Limit" section or all sections. (i.e. RDBMS high availability, RDBMS scalability and performance, RDBMS security, etc. from Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2019 page). Each version has its uniqueness. I understand that from EE to DE it shouldn't matter. Only when downgrading to SE, Express or Web. I will start with Start-DbaMigration as this will allow for side-by-side comparisons. Thanks for all your help and time.